# SQL Sorting on Fullname Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a fullname column, called `userFullName`

I am trying to create a proper select statement to show a '-Select User-' value for a drop-down, but order the resultset by last name in the `userFullName` field.

How can I:

1. Get the sort to properly work?
2. Still keep the -Select User- as the very first option?

SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    0 As UserID, '-Select User-' As UsersName, '' As Surname 

UNION ALL

SELECT
    userID As UserID, userFullName As UsersName, 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([userFullName]), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([userFullName])))) As Surname 
FROM 
    vwSelectUser 
ORDER BY 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([userFullName]), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([userFullName]))))
```

I am receiving the following error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'userFullName'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'userFullName'.
>   Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Yes, `userFullName` is a valid column in `vwSelectUser`

Comment: If you ain't got a real LastName column, your sort is, AFAIK, impossible. Imagine a full name like `Felipe Juan Froilán de Todos los Santos` or simply `Ernst Von Arx`...

Comment: why you shouldn't treat names this way. http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Really guys... I understand how things should or should have been done, but inheriting a 7 year old system, with a limited budget rewriting the processes for names are not in the scope of a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the *best* way is to store first and last names separately, but with what you've got you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    Select 0 As UserID, '-Select User-' As UsersName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'') As Surname 
    Union All 
    Select userID As UserID, userFullName As UsersName, 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([userFullName]), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([userFullName])))) As Surname 
    From vwSelectUser 
) AS A
Order By Surname
```

Comment: Yeah, while there are no more issues with it, the `Surname` column is blank... note, not NULL, but blank, and does not appear to be sorting

Comment: @o7thWebDesign, trying doing rtrim on the [userFullName]. This blank problem can be due to trailing empty space in your userFullName column.

Comment: Yep, that did it... man, just shows me just how dirty the data is in here...  the db I inherited has stuff like nicknames in parens, phone numbers, etc... all inside the FullName field  LMAO

Comment: @o7thWebDesign It may be truncating to 0 characters since only the length of `''` can be determined absolutely.  I changed by answer to force the result to 100-characters wide.